# Unusual CSVs Showing Up in Var/Export

Tags: magento-1.7, export, dataflow

Recently, we noticed there are 4 files being constantly exported to var/export. It contains what appears to be billing/payment info for customers - even though our Magento store doesn't store any credit card information.

We've confirmed with our host that these files haven't been accessed by anyone via the logs, but no matter what we do - deleting them, renaming var/export - they are still being constantly generated with the same file name and new entries are being recorded into it.

We didn't notice any recently modified php or phtml files that would indicate a hack, not sure how to trace to the source of the problem.

Does anyone have an idea on how to check what is causing these csv files to be generated? Could it possibly be some bug or something?

Comment: could you please give us the names the files have? this could help us identify the issue.

Comment: Yes, the file names are always export_274_prod.csv and export_mage274.csv

Comment: I don't know such files. The names looks weird...

Comment: The names look custom to me. Could it be that someone has created a custom script on your site to make these exports?

Comment: same issue - did you ever resolve?

Comment: Yes, actually. Must have got caught up in the moment and not responded. The site ended up being hacked - I believe Magento became aware of the issue a few months later and released a patch that dealt with the way it had been hacked.